# Input and div below with same widths should have aligned vertical borders

Tags: html, css

I have a container with inner INPUT and DIV below (class="inner-div"). All 3 widths are the same (container's width = input's width. Inner-div width = container's with (= input's width).

I want inner-div to have a border which vertically lies exactly on the same line, as input's border. How can I reach that? (Tried playing with border and outline, no success).

Probably the pic explains it: [Explaining Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qynl.jpg)

And here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergeyfomin/gu95fr7t/)

HTML and CSS:

```css
.container {
  background: purple;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.inner-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="input">
  <div class="inner-container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlines are not the same as borders.

*Just for double confirmation, use `box-sizing:border-box` so that borders are included in width calculations.*

If you wanted a border, just use one.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  background: purple;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
.input {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.inner-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="input">
  <div class="inner-div">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Paulie!
I did use "border", but it didn't work without "border-box". Thank you)